# How to set CSS hover effect, on parent and child elements

Tags: css, hover

Let's say i have the following code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

On hover for a *wrapper* I want it's child *title* div to change it's background color.
Can I do this in pure css. In js I know how to do it. I'm interested if a pure CSS method exists for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. It's just:

```
.wrapper:hover .title {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Please note that IE6 recognizes `:hover` only on `a`-elements, so this won't work - but i hope you don't have to mess with that crappy old thing.

Comment: @James: thanks for that, i was just about to create a fiddle myself ;)

Comment: Thanks for your note. About 6-7 months ago I decided that I will not care about Ie6 anymore. If somebody use it, he doesn't deserve a good looking website.

Comment: you're lucky - i have to maintain some old intranet-sites where 95% of the users are IE6 -.-' (PS: please consider marking my answer as acceptet if this was the solution you were looking for - and try to work on your accept-rate a little more, 79% may deter people from answering your questions)

Answer (score 6):

what about this?

```
.wrapper:hover .title {
    background-color: blue;
}
```